# Angular Library: Error: export 'X' (imported as 'X') was not found in 'my-pkg/my-lib' (possible exports MyLibComponent, MyLibModule, MyLibService)

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to package a set of classes into an Angular Library.
I followed the steps here: https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries:

```
ng new my-pkg --no-create-application
cd my-pkg
ng generate library my-lib
```

I then removed the generated module, component and service, and added my own classes.

I added explicit exports in public-api.ts, example:

```
export { MyLibServiceFactory } from './lib/my-lib-service-factory';
export { MyLibService } from './lib/my-lib-service';
export { MyLibConfiguration } from './lib/my-lib-configuration';
```

The library compiles without any errors or warnings.
I import it into my app.module.ts with:

```
import { MyLibServiceFactory, MyLibConfiguration } from "@my-pkg/my-lib";
```

However, when I try to compile I get:

```
./src/app/app.module.ts:51:241-260 - Error: export 'MyLibServiceFactory' (imported as 'MyLibServiceFactory') was not found in '@my-pkg/my-lib' (possible exports: MyLibComponent, MyLibModule, MyLibService)

./src/app/app.module.ts:52:15-33 - Error: export 'MyLibConfiguration ' (imported as 'MyLibConfiguration ') was not found in '@my-pkg/my-lib' (possible exports: MyLibComponent, MyLibModule, MyLibService)
```

I am pretty convinced I am missing something simple, but I have been searching for about 4 hours now, without any luck.

I am working with Angular 15 and Typescript 4.9
The library uses some Angular core methods like HttpClient.

Comment: In your `public-api.ts`, do you also expose `MyLibComponent` and `MyLibModule`? Because the error message says these are possible exports. I suspect this could be a caching issue. Did you try clearing the `.angular` folder of your application project?

Comment: It appears it was a caching issue, after deleting the content of the .angular folder and rebuilding, the errors went away. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Wow thank you! I was stuck on the same issue. This did the trick

Comment: also using angular 15. i exported the model classes but it cant be found if i use it in the web application. i did the same thing you did.